# Reemplazar \ por / con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando reemplazar todas las barras `\` por `/` dentro de un input con jquery de la siguiente manera

```js
//  input val -> G:\Ficheros\Documentacion\PROYECTOS\FILES\document.PDF
$("input").focusout(function() {
    var replaceSlashes = $(this).val().replace("\\", "/");
    $(this).val(replaceSlashes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="G:\Ficheros\Documentacion\PROYECTOS\FILES\document.PDF"/>
```

Pero sólo me sustituye la primera `\`, y si vuelvo a hacer **focusout**, se sustituye la segunda y así sucesivamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función replace solo cambia la primera ocurrencia si le pasas como primer parámetro un string:

> El método replace() devuelve una nueva cadena con algunas o todas las coincidencias de un patrón, siendo cada una de estas coincidencias reemplazadas por remplazo. **El patrón puede ser una cadena o una RegExp**, y el reemplazo puede ser una cadena o una función que será llamada para cada coincidencia. **Si el patrón es una cadena, sólo la primera coincidencia será reemplazada.**

Pero si en lugar de usar como primer parámetro un string, utilizas una expresión regular, le puedes añadir el parámetro `g` al final que sirve para indicar todas las ocurrencias.

> **g**: búsqueda global (global match); encuentra todos los resultados en vez de parar después de la primer búsqueda exitosa

Fíjate que para eso hay que quitar las comillas, encerrar la cadena entre barras y detrás de las barras poner el parámetro `g`, es decir: `/\\/g`

Te quedaría esto que puedes probar haciendo click en `Ejecutar`:

```js
$("input").focusout(function() {
    var replaceSlashes = $(this).val().replace(/\\/g, "/");
    $(this).val(replaceSlashes);
});
```

```css
input { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="G:\Ficheros\Documentacion\PROYECTOS\FILES\document.PDF"/>
```

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp